# Eliminate mismatch between building images and their shape file annotations

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, openstreetmap, remote-sensing

I have little experience with geospatial data processing. I have a satellite image of an area (a geotiff file) and building footprints (building annotations) for this area (a shape file). When I open both files in QGIS, I can see a mismatch between buildings and their annotations. The mismatch is about 20 meters on the ground.

The geotiff is in EPSG:32647 - WGS 84/UTM zone 47N. The shape file is in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.

The shape file was downloaded from Open Street Map (http://download.geofabrik.de/), the geotiff is from a closed external source.

The area contains about 10000 buildings. What would be the easiest way to eliminate this mismatch? If necessary, we could write some code or do some manual work.

**UPDATE:**

I reprojected the shape file to the CRS of the geotiff file in QGIS. I used `Vector` > `Data Management Tools` > `Reproject Layer...` menu. It did not have any effect at all (building annotations are still at exactly the same locations).

Comment: Please provide CRS for both data sets, as well as how both were created.

Comment: @Erik, I updated my post.

Comment: You can check the CRS in the layer properties, topmost tab.

Comment: @Erik, thank you! I updated my question again.

Comment: Have you seen [this question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345701/qgis-3-10-1-shapefile-layer-and-imported-aerial-are-not-matching-up) it is similar and may help

Comment: @RJAM, thanks! So probably my first step should be trying to re-project one of the files/layers to the CRS of the other. I'll figure out how it can be done in QGIS, and will try it on Monday.

Comment: @RJAM, I reprojected the shape file and updated my question. For some reason it did not have any effect.